# (pam_ldap.so) /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found

Tags: glibc, openldap, pam

I am testing a Linux-PAM installation with this [test program](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/adg-example.html). When the pam_ldap.so module is called, the test program application fails with a segmentation error. Looking at the /var/log/messages, I can red the following error message:

```
petalinux authpriv.err pam_test: PAM unable to dlopen(/usr/lib/security/pam_ldap.so): /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /usr/lib/libldap-2.4.so.2)
petalinux authpriv.err pam_test: PAM adding faulty module: /usr/lib/security/pam_ldap.so
```

The system is an embedded Linux running on a Zynq processor.
Can anyone help me understand the source of the problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone help me understand the source of the problem?

You linked `libldap-2.4.so.2` against GLIBC-2.28 (or later).
But at runtime, the version of GLIBC is 2.27 (or earlier).

GLIBC supports backward compatibility (binaries built against earlier version of GLIBC continue to run on systems with newer GLIBC versions).

But it doesn't support "build on newer, run on older" compatibility.

Comment: Thank you. By running /lib/libc.so.6 on the target board, I get the output: "GNU C Library (GNU libc) stable release version 2.23". In this case, I suppose I have to look for a pam_ldap.so (or libldap-2.4??) which supports the older libc library (2.23) instead of the 2.28. Can you please confirm this?

Comment: @user15061000 That's correct: you need to build (or find) a version of `libldap-2.4.so.2` that was linked against appropriate version of `libc.so.6`.